# How can I ensure a function is fully applied?

Tags: haskell

In the following code, the `where value=` clause returns a partially applied function.

How can I ensure it gets fully applied?

```
------------------------------
future_value :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
future_value present interest periods =
  (present * (( 1 + interest) ** periods))

------------------------------
-- Given an initial amount
-- Given a yearly fee, as well as a yearly interest...
-- Calculates return over a number of years, given a yearly fee.
return_over_time :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
return_over_time present interest num_years fee =
  if num_years == 1 then (future_value  present interest 1.0) - fee
  else future_value value
       where value =  return_over_time present interest (num_years - 1) fee
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue isn't with `value` but with `future_value`. `future_value` takes three arguments but you only give it one (`value`), so `future_value value` has the type `Float -> Float - > Float`. `value`, on the other hand, is just a `Float` because `return_over_time` is fully applied in the `where` clause.

You can make sure `future_value` is fully applied by passing in two more floats for `interest` and `periods`.

Incidentally, is there any particular reason you are using `Float` instead of `Double`?

Comment: No, I just wanted a decimal-y number. Technically, I should find a Decimal type.

Comment: Also, thanks. I stared at that code so long I missed the fact I was missing args.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes no sense that a function is ever partially applied, you can change it to take a tuple:

```
future_value :: (Float, Float, Float) -> Float
future_value (present, interest, periods) =
   (present * (( 1 + interest) ** periods))
```

Using this definition error messages get much more "localized", the compiler will complain about passing a `(Float, Float)` instead of `(Float,Float,Float)` or so, and not about something fancy like a missing `Show` instance for `(->)`. However this is just a little trick for beginners, as for most functions currying makes a lot of sense, and sooner or later you get used to it and learn to fix errors resulting from missing arguments quickly.